# Convert mm/dd/yyyy string into timestamp in MySQL

Tags: mysql, date

I have a column in a MySQL table where dates are stored as a mm/dd/yyyy string. I need to preserve that column as is, so I have added a new column where I want to store that date as a timestamp. What would the query look like to take column a and convert it to a timestamp and put it into the new column b?

Comment: There is a manual for this stuff.

Comment: Link to this specific task in the manual?

Answer (score 1):

you can use **STR_TO_DATE** to convert your string like

```
select str_to_date('02/22/2013','%m/%d/%Y');


UPDATE YourTable set newCol = str_to_date(yourOldCol,'%m/%d/%Y');
```

Comment: How do I put it in the new column?

Comment: Don't I have to select the column by name, like select str_to_date(column_name, '%m/%d/%Y') ?

Comment: @poptartgun -  i have add it in my anwser

Comment: ok thank you for the help

Comment: Hmmm I tried that and ended up with like 20160416 in the new column.

Comment: I'm looking for a timestamp, like seconds since epoch.